# Error: Microsoft Word Sorry, we ran into a problem. on Documents generated with Open-XML-SDK

Tags: office365, openxml, sharepoint-online, openxml-sdk

We sporadically get the following error: Microsoft Word Sorry, we ran into a problem, when opening Word docx documents in office365 browser.

[image]

If we open the docx with the desktop version of Office everything works.

The problem occurs repeatedly with documents generated a few weeks or months ago and stored in a SharePoint online document library.

If the document is regenerated, the error does not occur anymore, but after some time it can lead to this problem again.

We use DocumentFormat.OpenXml version 2.9.1 to generate the Word documents.

We already reworked the code two months ago to generate valid XML, but now the error comes back anyway.

Does anyone have an idea or a hint on how we can narrow down this bug or also such experiences?

Does anyone know stable alternatives to OpenXml to generate Word documents?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your document URL ends with "&action=view" just remove and try.